# Jni UnsatisfiedLinkError. native library has been added and there is no error in the cpp file

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, native

i'm just trying to play with native library.
after a struggle trying I finally got this error

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:test.JniTest.hei(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at test.JniTest.hei(Native Method)
at test.JniTest.main(JniTest.java:11)
```

i have already added my dll files in Native library location.
this is my java files:

```
package test; 
public class JniTest {
  static{System.loadLibrary("module");}
  public native void hei(String x); 
  public static void main(String args[]){   
    JniTest jni=new   JniTest();    
    jni.hei("nothing"); 
  } 
}
```

there is no error in cpp files or in header files. everything work perfectly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test_JniTestx.h"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_JniTest_hei(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring x){
    printf("something");
}
```

ps:sorry for my bad english

Comment: your dll file is in 32 bit or 64 bit? also what about your java ? Is it 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: my os 64bit. my eclipse 32bit. my mingw 32 bit. my jdk 32 bit and my compiled dll also 32 bit.

Comment: Ok. I asked this because that's where your problem lies. Everything you try to combine should be either in 32 bit or 64 bit. Otherwise you will have `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. I still doubt. Are you sure you have everything in 32 bit?

Comment: if iam using jdk 64 bit exception should like this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\project_folder\Eclipse_project\Test1\module.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform.

Comment: I am not talking about jdk only. I am talking about everything : mingw, your compiled dll etc.

Comment: yeah iam sure my mingw is 32 bit

Comment: A 32/64 bit issue would produce a different error message. Java can load the library but doesn't find a matching function for `hei` in it.

Comment: @Chirag parmar thank you so much. its work!  iam just using visual c++ 2008 now instead of mingw. this is works for both 32 and 64.

Comment: @user2543253 its looks like cdt passing wrong argument to mingw gcc. its work as i expected if i build it only via comandline

Comment: Great..!! Cheers..!!